# Two differential forms are the same if they are the same locally.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

> Two differential forms are the same if they are the same locally.

Why is it the case? Could anyone give me some suggestions in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How did your book define differential forms? Can you see why "two ordinary functions are the same if they are the same locally"?

Comment: The same locally *at every point* :)

Answer (score 1):

A differential $k$-form on $M$ is a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)) of the $k$th [exterior power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) of the [cotangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_bundle)... Whatever that means.

Important for your question is that a differential $k$-form is a special smooth function $\alpha : M \to \bigwedge^k T^* M$, where the codomain is just some manifold (which was cleverly constructed to classify differential $k$-forms on $M$!). So your question is really about whether two smooth functions which agree locally must be the same.

If by "locally" you mean "for each point $p$ there's a neighborhood $U$ so that $\alpha \restriction_U = \beta \restriction_U$", then yes -- $\alpha = \beta$, since they're just functions.

If by "locally" you mean that there's *some* neighborhood where $\alpha \restriction_U = \beta \restriction_U$, then not necessarily. After all, there's no reason two smooth functions which agree in some neighborhood have to agree everywhere!

---

As an aside, this is one of the reasons to gain some familiarity with these high-abstraction ways of talking about $k$-forms (or other mathematical topics too). For computations, you almost always want to be working with coordinate charts, but for these kinds of "does everything work nicely?" abstract questions, having some machinery with a simpler language can help make certain things obvious that are *far* from obvious when we have to worry about coordinate charts and transition functions.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: If the underlying domain manifold is connected then two smooth functions are globally equal iff there is a non-empty open set on which they agree. Am I right?

Comment: That's not right. For instance, there are smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ which are constantly $1$ inside $(-1,1)$ but are _not_ the constant $1$ function. These are actually extremely useful functions to consider! See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) for instance. However, if your functions are both [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), then your claim is true. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).